# How to find out which layers of a docker image are part of the base image

Tags: docker, layer, docker-registry

Is there any way to get which layers of a docker images comes from the base image (inherited from the FROM instruction) using the docker registry API?

I want to analyze the new layers added by my Dockerfile. To do that, I need to filter and isolate just the new layers, leaving apart every layer that come from the original base image and I do not see a trustful way to do it with response that I get after calling

*myregistry/v2/myimage/manifests/mytag*

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd need to query the base image, then your image and come up with the difference. Tags can reference different entities over time though so you might run into issues if you are reporting this some time after the build has occurred.

You could [inspect the images](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.27/#operation/ImageInspect) or [check the history](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.27/#operation/ImageHistory) in the Docker Engine API as well, and come up with the layer differences in the same way.

Comment: That's my backup solution but I was trying to do it without knowing the base image to avoid asking extra information to our users.

Comment: An image has an array of fs layers referenced by their sha256 checksum, I don't think docker stores details of the `FROM` or Dockerfile hierarchy used in the build process.